# Simple password protecting of a page: What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: php, html, session, post

For my test environment site I want anyone who views it to have to type in a password once per session. When their session starts, they type in the password and are redirected to the page they were trying to view. So I have at the top of every page

```
// For test site, require login
if ( !$_SESSION['loggedIn'] )
{
    $pagetarget = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    include "test_login.php";
    die();
}
```

and then `test.login.php` is

```
<?php 
    if ( $_POST['password'] == '091u233j12j3' )
    {  
       $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
       header("Location: " . $pagetarget);
       die();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test Environment Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <p>Enter password to unlock <b>test.mysite.com</b>: <input type="text" name="password" /><input type="submit" /></p>
        <p>You will be redirected to the page you tried to access.</p>
        <input type="hidden" name="pagetarget" value="<?php echo $pagetarget; ?>" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

but the page redirection isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a thought but can't you use Javascript and document.location to redirect the page? ... for example document.location.href="http://www.google.com";

Comment: Did you check the value of page redirect since you're not in the same file ?

Comment: Have you got [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) anywhere?

Comment: @user3362232 anything you do in javascript can be trivially bypassed by a moderately knowledgable user, and is no protection at all.  Although this Q is not about "real" security you should still _always_ do your checks and validations on the server, and _never_ trust what the browser sends you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a call to `session_start()` at the beginning of every script before you can use `$_SESSION`.

Example:

```
session_start();
if ( !$_SESSION['loggedIn'] )
{
    $pagetarget = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    include "test_login.php";
    die();
}
```

Comment: That worked. But why at the beginning of every script? Like I said, I want this to be a one-and-done.

Comment: @PeterThiel it needs to be done only on scripts you check (or set) `$_SESSION['loggedIn']` or any other `$_SESSION` variable on. If you are checking it on every page, you must do it on every page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
// For test site, require login
session_start(); 
if ( !$_SESSION['loggedIn'] )
{
    $pagetarget = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    include "test_login.php";
    die();
}
```

and `test_login.php`

```
<?php 
if ( $_POST['password'] == '091u233j12j3' )
{  
   $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
   header("Location: " . $_POST['$pagetarget']);
   die();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
(...)
```

Comment: That would still fail as he is checking the `$_SESSION['loggedIn']` before including this code. The `session_start()` should go before the check.